# File size exceeds objects sizes

Tags: objects

While revising an existing blender file, I realized it was getting way too big as it approached 1GB.  This didn't look right since the objects were relatively simple.  I copied/pasted all the objects to a new file which is under 300MB.  Why the difference?

Comment: Mind uploading that crazily large file somewhere (wetransfer, megashare ...)? Maybe there are some baked modifiers (Mesh Cage Bind) or lots of / large packed textures.

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49062/what-are-common-causes-for-blend-files-growing-in-size)

Comment: Sorry but can't upload file b/c it's intellectual property..already read and tried troubleshooting using above ques and answers...would modifiers and textures be copied over to new file with objects?

Comment: Modifiers will be copied, as part of object data being copied (when copying object itself). Textures are saved in materials only as links to file unless explicitly packed, so they should be transferred as settings of the material setup and work properly in new file (if their location on the hdd hasn't changed)

Comment: So if I Cntrl+C copy objects in original large file and Cntrl+V paste to new file, will textures and modifiers copy over too?  But whether or not it does, original ques remains--why is new file about 1/3 size of original file?